# Tilde symbol on zshell, alternative shortcut

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I can't display tilde symbol on zshell. ~

It works outside of terminal. Also works on bash shell. So I suspected zshell.
I don't want to stop using zshell while I am starting to like. Is there any other way?

Comment: Edit: Tilde symbol doesn't work on bash too. It puts ? instead.

Comment: The default `PROMPT` in `zsh` contains `#` for a privileged user and `%` for a non-privileged user.  You can edit the `~/.zshrc` file to modify it for the current user.  You can search Google on how to customize the `zsh` command prompt.

Comment: I don't wanna be rude but you did not really help by asking to do a google search. Forget it, i will use iTerm2.

Comment: Setting aside that your question probably isn't appropriate on SO and should have been asked on Super User or similar, I gave you the name and location of the configuration file and since the rest is already out there on the Internet it seemed senseless to replicate the contents of numerous other posts that provide an answer to your question.  BTW your post really was not very clear so what I thought you were asking may not have been so and as such if the info I provided is not relevant then improve the quality of your question.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to terminal staff. The problem: I stroke the key combination for the ~ "tilde" but it doesn't work. It works here like ~~~~

Comment: I guess your saying that you can't type the tilde `~` character in the terminal, is that correct?  I have no problem typing it in `bash` or `zsh`, so without additional information the only suggestion I have is to check your keyboard layout, regional settings and terminal settings.

Comment: I can type on bash too. when i choose zshell, the same combination doesn't work. It works on iTerm2's zshell too. But i didn't like iTerm's performance and look. I have a different keyboard, yes but i don't think that is the problem. I think zshell and default terminal changing something.

Comment: I found the cause of my problem. It was the theme i was using. I will answer so maybe it helps someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is irrelevant but the theme i was using is the source of my problem. There is open issues on github for the theme since 2 years.

The github page is here: tomorrow-theme -> 
https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme

Maybe it helps someone.